# Disable checkbox on certain lines on a JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have a JTable on a Netbeans 8.2 project which shows the data of a list a class (let's call it Client) and a checkbox on the first column of each line. I've setup this way changing the data type of the column in the object's properties menu. How can I not show this checkbox in case that a client's attribute is false?

Comment: You can always not show a certain component by calling `setVisible(false)` on it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first column is not editable. If you want to hide the JCheckBox when cell value is false, you can use a customer cell renderer:

```
private class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col)
    {
        Component c;
        if (((Boolean)value).equals(true))
        {
            // Use the default renderer for Boolean which is JCheckBox based
            c = myTable.getDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(col)).getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        } else
        {
            // Use the standard default renderer which is a JLabel
            c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            if (c instanceof JLabel)
            {
                ((JLabel) c).setText(null);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

And apply it on the first boolean column:

```
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```